# How to utilize excel data in List<map> object with DataProvider?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am using an Excel driver to get UserIDs and Passwords from my spreadsheet. I am creating the Excel Driver object and using a method of the Excel Driver class to get the data and store it as `Map<String,Object>> testData`.

This is implemented in my `DataProvider` method. I am having trouble passing the values to my main Test method.

I am able to get values for 1 row at a time and pass to the main test method, but I would like to be able to pass all 3 rows of user credentials.

```
// This returns a List with a map that represents every row in spreadsheet

List<Map<String, Object>> testData = excelDriver.getData();


// The following code works to get data for the first row, but I need to understand how to 
// return all UserIDs and Passwords (3 rows total) for use in the main Test.

@DataProvider(name="dataProvider")
public Object [] dataProvider() throws IOException {
    Map<String, Object> nmap = testData.get(1);
    Object userID = nmap.get("USER_ID");  // user ID column header
    Object password = nmap.get("Password"); // password column header
    return new Object [] {{userID, password}};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your code, each row is represented as an array of objects, so you have to return a `List <Object[]>` to get all the rows.

```
@DataProvider(name="dataProvider")
public List<Object[]> dataProvider() {
  List<Map<String, Object>> testData = excelDriver.getData();
  return testData.stream().map( row -> dataMapper(row)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private Object [] dataMapper(Map<String, Object> nmap) {
    Object userID = nmap.get("USER_ID");  // user ID column header
    Object password = nmap.get("Password"); // password column header
    return new Object [] {userID, password};
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. I'm still stuck on getting the individual strings back for user ID and password thoigh. Do I need to recreate the map object within the Test Class to grab the string values?  Thank you

Comment: @dobogdas  maybe you could create a class that has String user, password and then "map" those values from the data you get from the "driver" ? Because with your current code you will need to do something like `String user = (String) row[0]; String pasword = (String) row[1]`, and that way is error prone (ClassCastException) and not really "pretty" to do.